# Всегда ли не обособляется оборот «и все такое»?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

Наверное, Грамота.ру знает, как правильно.

**Вопрос № 298509**
Подскажите, выделяется ли запятыми выражение «и всё такое»?
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Слова «и все такое» **обычно не обособляются.**
Запятая перед ними может ставиться при определенном строе предложения (например, если есть повторяющийся союз).

Сочетание **часто употребляется** в разговорной речи (1400 примеров в Нацкорпусе). В основном пишут без обособления (так правила велят), но и обособленный оборот тоже встречается.

Понятно **отсутствие запятой** в таком предложении, где И — замыкающий соединительный союз: *Приусадебные наделы, личные огороды **и всё такое**…* [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

Но в некоторых случаях союз И явно **присоединительный** (оборот как бы обобщает тематику высказывания), а иногда это может быть авторским выбором. **Интонационно** все объясняется просто: ударение на предыдущем слове и пауза как следствие.

И вопрос: **можно ли обособлять оборот** и как поступаете вы, если его употребляете? Или ревнители правил могут сделать вам замечание: **неправильно, ошибка!**

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

Уперлись, как бараны: здесь наши деды рождались и умирали, здесь наша молодость прошла, **и все такое.** [Александра Маринина. (2014)]

Там и хлеба свежего купим, **и всё такое…** [Аркадий Мацанов, 2014]

Мол, не стоит тебе лишний раз в Москву заявляться. Нечего тут делать, **и все такое.** [Г. М. Артемьева. (2012)]

За то, что обманул: женился без любви, **и всё такое**. [Д. Н. Гуцко, 2012]

― Гнет стран третьего мира, **ну и все такое**, ― говорит он. [В. В. Лорченков, 2011]

Цветы, подарки в виде тележки памперсов, **и всё такое**. [Татьяна Соломатина. (2010)]

Не то чтобы лежачего не бьют ― **и всё такое**, хотя и это тоже [В. Ю. Кунгурцева. (2009)]

― Вы, конечно, тоже из тех, кто ля-ля-ля правосудие-законность, **и все такое…** [Дина Рубина (2008-2009)]

Answer (score 3):

Оно по смыслу равняется "и т. п.".

У Розенталя есть такое (просто интересное правило):
Слова «и т. д.» («и так далее»), «и т. п.» («и тому подобное»), имеющие общее значение, не приравниваются к однородным членам предложения, и запятая перед ними не ставится, если даже союз и повторяется при однородных членах, находящихся перед указанными словами, например: *Он увлекался и лыжами, и коньками, и хоккеем и т. д. К семейству злаковых относится и рожь, и пшеница, и ячмень и т. п.*

> Можно ли обособлять оборот?

Можно, но могут заподозрить ошибку, потому что присоединение (сказать вдобавок, новой фразой) здесь довольно нестандартно.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.