# Нужно ли ставить запятые в этих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужны ли запятые тут?

1. На стыке **но(,) то, что**.

Не знаю, зачем эти люди поселились у нас, **но(,) то, что** настроены они враждебно, исключать нельзя.

2. Перед **и всё такое**.

Мой дом - твой дом, мой чай - твой чай... **и всё такое**.

Я бы и сам отнёс Алексею деньги, но у меня тут дела есть важные, а этот козёл шум поднимает - просрочка, счётчик(,) **и все такое**.

Comment: По каким соображениям эти запятые нужны? Тот, кто сказал, что они нужны, назвал причину?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Не знаю, *зачем эти люди поселились у нас*, но то, **что настроены они враждебно**, исключать нельзя.*

Сложное предложение, четыре предикативные основы, союз ***НО*** обозначает сочинительную связь. Обособлены два изъяснительных **придаточных** предложения.

2. **Перед "и всё такое"**

*Мой дом — твой дом, мой чай — твой чай... **и всё такое**.* Или: *Мой дом — твой дом, мой чай — твой чай, **и всё такое.***  Присоединительный союз И.

*Я бы и сам отнёс Алексею деньги, но у меня тут дела есть важные, а этот козёл шум поднимает — **просрочка, счётчик и все такое.*** Однородные члены.

**№ 298509**. Подскажите, выделяется ли запятыми выражение «и всё такое»? ОТВЕТ. Слова ***и все такое*** обычно не обособляются. Запятая перед ними может ставиться при определенном строе предложения (например, если есть повторяющийся союз).

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472177/Всегда-ли-не-обособляется-оборот-и-все-такое](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472177/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5)